# Information about DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM attribute EXPORT

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle9i, ojdbc

I am using the  `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` utility to extract DDL from Oracle database  and I need information about the `EXPORT` parameter for the Procedure `DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM`, I can't find anything about it in the official documentation and apparently it's not the only case.
after testing extracting objects with and without that parameter the only thing that I noticed is that when the `EXPORT` is set to `False` the views object are extracted with `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`   otherwise they are extracted with only `CREATE  VIEW`.

Could any one explain to me what the EXPORT PARAMETER do exactly ??

Note :I am using JDBC to generate DLL.

Code Snippet Below :

" `DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'EXPORT',TRUE);"`

Comment: If it isn't documented you usually shouldn't be using it; although it's mentioned in MOS doc ID 1491820.1 and maybe others. From the name it looks like something used internally by data pump to generate DDL in a specific format (and current state, for partitions, apparently). How did you know it existed, and why are you trying to use it (or even just know what it's for)?

Comment: I am maintaining an app that generate ddl and I just found it there :) , i want to know what the Export param do before removing it.